# Heroku выдает ошибку при загрузке файлов на сторонний ftp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ftp, heroku

Пользуюсь Paperclip и Хероку. При создании поста (модель Post) Paperclip загружает файлы с помощью гема "paperclip-storage-ftp" на сторонний ФТП. На локальной машине все грузится и показывает нормально, но после деплоя на Хероку при создании поста вылетает ошибка "We're sorry, but something went wrong." и пост не создается. Логи выдают следующее:

```
2016-05-14T13:50:25.610993+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] saving ftp://user@ftp.site.com:public_html/site.com/paperclip/images/9/medium/heroku-og-cad174838a49b266550809e29026ec9bc18e056dae8f9cf523ea4237379691f9.png
2016-05-14T13:50:25.610833+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] saving ftp://user@ftp.site.com:public_html/site.com/paperclip/images/9/small/heroku-og-cad174838a49b266550809e29026ec9bc18e056dae8f9cf523ea4237379691f9.png
2016-05-14T13:50:25.610678+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] saving ftp://user@ftp.site.com:public_html/site.com/paperclip/images/9/original/heroku-og-cad174838a49b266550809e29026ec9bc18e056dae8f9cf523ea4237379691f9.png
2016-05-14T13:50:26.139144+00:00 app[web.1]:    (2.2ms)  ROLLBACK
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141032+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2016-05-14T13:50:26.139691+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3926ms (ActiveRecord: 24.5ms)
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141022+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141031+00:00 app[web.1]: Net::FTPPermError (500 I won't open a connection to 172.18.180.250 (only to 23.23.61.72)
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141038+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:418:in `transfercmd'
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141036+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141038+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:513:in `block (2 levels) in retrlines'
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141035+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:362:in `block in voidcmd'
2016-05-14T13:50:26.140951+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/posts" host=arcane-taiga-31170.herokuapp.com request_id=6ad00282-fea1-44d3-aa16-7c59877f7954 fwd="92.100.238.86" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4237ms status=500 bytes=1714
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141037+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:376:in `sendport'
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141036+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:360:in `voidcmd'
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141033+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:327:in `getresp'
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141034+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:339:in `voidresp'
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141040+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141039+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:199:in `with_binary'
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141043+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/paperclip-storage-ftp-1.2.7/lib/paperclip/storage/ftp/server.rb:103:in `mktree'
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141040+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:511:in `block in retrlines'
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141045+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/paperclip-storage-ftp-1.2.7/lib/paperclip/storage/ftp.rb:49:in `block (3 levels) in flush_writes'
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141042+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:743:in `nlst'
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141046+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141041+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:510:in `retrlines'
2016-05-14T13:50:26.141044+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/paperclip-storage-ftp-1.2.7/lib/paperclip/storage/ftp/server.rb:68:in `put_files'
```

Установки Paperclip в модели Post:

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { small: "350x250>", medium: "700x500#" },
                    default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png",
                    :storage => :ftp,
                    :path => "public_html/site.com/paperclip/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
                    :url => "http://site.com/paperclip/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
                    :ftp_servers => [
                        {
                            :host     => "ftp.site.com",
                            :user     => "user",
                            :password => "password"
                        },
                    ],
                    :ftp_connect_timeout => 5, # optional, nil by default (OS default timeout)
                    :ftp_ignore_failing_connections => true, # optional, false by default
                    :ftp_keep_empty_directories => true # optional, false by default
```

Comment: https://github.com/xing/paperclip-storage-ftp/issues/11 ?

Comment: Спасибо, подошло.

Comment: Напишите ответ, пожалуйста. Мне лень %)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена добавлением строки ":passive  => true" в файле модели:

```
:ftp_servers => [
                        {
                            :host     => "site.com",
                            :user     => "user",
                            :password => "password",
                            :passive  => true
}
```